# Object.keys.map only return the nth values and exclude the rest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, javascript-objects

I have an object `tooltip`

```
var showTooltip = Object.keys(tooltip).map(function(e) {
  console.log(tooltip[e])
  <div className="tooltip bold" style={{left: x, top: y, padding: '5px', fontSize: '12px'}}>{tooltip[e].Company}</div>
});
```

What is currently returning

```
<div class="tooltip bold" style="left: 529px; top: 394px; padding: 5px; font-size: 12px;"></div>
<div class="tooltip bold" style="left: 529px; top: 394px; padding: 5px; font-size: 12px;"></div>
<div class="tooltip bold" style="left: 529px; top: 394px; padding: 5px; font-size: 12px;">Company X, LLC</div>
<div class="tooltip bold" style="left: 529px; top: 394px; padding: 5px; font-size: 12px;"></div>
<div class="tooltip bold" style="left: 529px; top: 394px; padding: 5px; font-size: 12px;"></div>
<div class="tooltip bold" style="left: 529px; top: 394px; padding: 5px; font-size: 12px;"></div>
```

It is returning 6 `<div>`'s (1,2,4,5,6 I do not need to use); how do I only return the 3rd `<div>` that has the Company name data, or remove the ones with empty innerHTML?

Comment: You really shouldn't `map` over keys or `filter` them. You should know which key of the `tooltip` object contains the data, and then refer to that property directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filter` them out first:

```
var showTooltip = Object.keys(tooltip).filter(k => !!tooltip[k].Company).map(function(e) {
    console.log(tooltip[e])
    <div className="tooltip bold" style={{left: x, top: y, padding: '5px', fontSize: '12px'}}>{tooltip[e].Company}</div>
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Return `null` for items without a company:

```js
class Demo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var tooltip = this.props.tooltip;
    
    var showTooltip = Object.keys(tooltip).map(function(e) {
      var company = tooltip[e].Company;

      return company ? (
        <div key={e} className="tooltip bold" style={{left: 0, top: 0, padding: '5px', fontSize: '12px'}}>{company}</div>
      ) : null;
    });
    
    return (
      <div>
        {showTooltip}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

var tooltip = { a: { Company: 'a' }, b: {}, c: { Company: 'c' }};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo tooltip={tooltip} />,
  root
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Object.keys(tooltip) returns ARRAY of keys in given object.
That is why all array functions can be used here.

> map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling
> a provided function on every element in the calling array.
>
> filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the
> test implemented by the provided function.

As per the question, it seems you want to filter based on company name.
so you can simply try(may be syntax error):

```
var showTooltip = Object.keys(tooltip).map( e => tooltip[e].Company && 
   tooltip[e].Company !== '');

    showTooltip.map(tooltip => {
         console.log(tooltip[e])
         <div className="tooltip bold" style={{left: x, top: y, padding: '5px', 
          fontSize: '12px'}}>{tooltip[e].Company}</div>
       })
```

Ref:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter